# Simulation in R using a counter using mean

Tags: r, simulation

I have the following code to count how many times a normally distributed random number (mu =245, sd = 24.5, n = 9) goes below 200.

```
 # This is a simulation  to count the Binomial from B samples of
 # size n from a Normal population with mu and sigma that fall below 
 # a cutoff x_0   B = 100000; mu = 245; sigma = 24.5; n = 9  x_0 = 200 
 # for one sample  
 y_count = numeric(n) 
 y_average = numeric(n)
 x = numeric(n)  
for (i in 1:n){         
x[i] = rnorm(1,mu,sigma)         
    if (x[i] < x_0) y_count[i] = y_count[i] + 1 
}  
y_count  
sum(y_count) 

 # for B samples and computing the estimated probability 
 y_count = matrix(0,B,n) 
 x = matrix(0,B,n) 
 for (j in 1:B){         
      for (i in 1:n){                 
       x[j,i] = rnorm(1,mu,sigma)                
       if (x[j,i] < x_0) y_count[j,i] = y_count[j,i] + 1         
    } }  
 y_count  
 y_count_rows = apply(y_count,1,sum) 
 y_count_rows  
 prob_est = sum(y_count_rows)/B
 prob_est
```

I would like to be able to compute how often the average of the 9 replicates go below 200  how can I do that modififying this program in R

Comment: Could you simply use the pnorm() or 1-pnorm() to get the correct answer from the get-go, or are you planning to use this for something else?

Answer (score 3):

Could this work for you? It uses the pnorm( ) function, which is the cumulative density function (cdf) for the normal distribution. It returns the area below the given value of `x_0` for a given set of mean and sigma values.

```
mu=245
sigma = 24.5
x_0 = 200
pnorm(q=x_0, mean=mu, sd=sigma)

[1] 0.03312454
```

Namely, it states that about 3.31% of the draws from a random distribution with that mu and sigma will be below that threshold.